# Google Glass are bricked - receiving "Home/Camera/Voice stopped unexpectedly" errors

Tags: android, google-glass

Our research lab has several pair of Google Glass that we've been using in our research. Recently, one pair (that had been sitting in storage) stopped working - we booted them up about a month ago (they hadn't been used since April 2014) and during the boot sequence, we received several "stopped unexpectedly" errors (for Home, Camera, and Voice functions).

We spoke with Google twice on the issue, and they told us:

(1) The Glass likely lost a connection during a software update, so to do a factory reset we'd need the original device that the Glass were tethered to to initiate a factory reset. Sadly, we no longer have this device, so we cannot initiate a factory reset.

(2) The Glass are out of warranty, so they will not offer any further customer service, other than to direct us to StackOverflow. (stings a bit, to be honest)

So, my question ... there has to be a way to manually reset the Glass via USB? Any help or advice from this community would be incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can do [factory reset](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/6057546?hl=en) in Google Glass by doing this:

1. Tap the touchpad to activate Glass.
2. From the Home screen, swipe backward on the touchpad until you see the Settings bundle.
3. Tap into the Setting bundle and swipe forward until you see the **Device Info card.**
4. Tap again and swipe forward until you see **Factory Reset.**

Another method can be done using [Recovery Mode](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/6058759?hl=en).

To access Recovery Mode, turn off Glass. Hold the camera button, then press the power button once. Continue to hold the camera button for about 10 seconds, and Glass will go into Recovery Mode.

In Recovery Mode, you have the option to:

1. Reboot normally
2. Reboot into fast boot (This is mainly used by developers)
3. Factory reset (Removes your account, pictures, videos, and Glass settings from this device. If your Glass is having issues, this will give you a fresh start. **Warning:** If your pictures and videos haven’t been synced to Auto Backup, they will be erased. If you want to keep them, connect Glass to your computer using the USB cable and manually transfer the files.)
4. Sideline from adb (Also for developers)

Check also this [thread](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/gggeeks/how_to_factory_reset_google_glass/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with 2 pairs I have. I contacted Google support on this and they told me to power them on and leave them close to the last known WiFi access point they were connected to.

This has worked for 1 pair.  The other pair still has the same issues. I'll update if I find anything that worked.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem. Unfortunately, same boat ... device is out of warranty and turning the device on and update itself using the original Wifi or the paired phone is non-existent. Also seeking any way to refresh the "image" of the OS/program on the device via USB.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you also have the same problem as the original poster, please upvote the question instead.